# Add/Remove value to/from the dropdown Datasource on insert/delete value into/from the database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a dropdown on my webpage bound to sqlDataSource. We often add/remove values of the column from the database. When I insert a new value then it should be present in the dropdown list immediately, same way value should be removed from the dropdown once I delete that from database without using the refresh option/javascript's location.reload();. I tried the following for adding the value to the dropdown.

```
pr1.aspx:

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  DataTextField="dropval" DataValueField="dropval" Height="31px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VBTestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [dropval] FROM [pbs]"></asp:SqlDataSource> 

pr1.aspx.cs:

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=pbs;User Id=sa;Password=****;");
           con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select dropval from pbs", con);
            SqlDataAdapter dtAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt= new DataTable();
            dtAdapter.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "dropval";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "dropval";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select", "0"));
         }

        }
```

I am not facing any errors with this but this is not working. Not adding the value to the dropdown once I add new value in the database(able to see after refreshing the page).  I insert the values into the database using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Why don't you add the values to the datatable before assigning it to the dropdownlist

Comment: How can I do that here, I am adding values directly to the database not using any code for that.

Comment: DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["dropal"] = "select"
dt.Rows.Add(row);
DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList1.DataBind();

In case you want to insert in first position then use
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

Comment: The above is adding the string value("select" here) to the list, not the value that I added to the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call following code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=pbs;User Id=sa;Password=****;");
           con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select dropval from pbs", con);
            SqlDataAdapter dtAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt= new DataTable();
            dtAdapter.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "dropval";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "dropval";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("select", "0"));
```

at the `event` where you are adding/deleting the values to/from `databse`. Basically ou have to rebind the `dropdown list` to the latest values from the database.

Comment: I am not using any code to insert/delete the values. I am doing it using SSMS.

Comment: @M.K how your .net application will come to know hat data has been changed, you have o somehow notify the applicatiion

Comment: Is there a way to tell the application to always take the updated table.

Comment: you can use sql cache dependency in asp.net